# State space model parameterized by a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, estimation, state-space-models

For the sake of argument, assume the following simple state-space model:

- Transition model: $x_{t}=a\cdot x_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$
- Measurement model: $y_t=f(x_t)+\delta_t$

Assume $x_t$ and $y_t$ are 1D, while $\epsilon_t$ and $\delta_t$ are zero-mean Gaussian noise with some variances.
Function $f(x)$ is unknown and parameterized by a neural network.
How one would go about training this neural network?

Comment: This is something that [Neural Ordinary Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.02435) probably addresses. See also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366).